# NSCalendarUnit – modifying unitFlags

Tags: iphone, ios, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents, nsuinteger

In my app I want to let user set display style of a date. I've considered to just modify `unitFlags` to achieve that. I mean this

```
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

But here's the question: **How can I add or remove a `NSCalendarUnit` to this integer**?

I'm using `NSCalendar` to get `NSDateComponents` from a date.

Sorry if the question is too stupid, I wasn't working enough with bitwise operations :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can add a flag using the 
"bitwise or" operator:

```
unitFlags |= NSYearCalendarUnit;
```

and remove a flag using "bitwise and" in combination with "bitwise complement";

```
unitFlags &= ~NSYearCalendarUnit;
```

To check for a flag:

```
if ((unitFlags & NSYearCalendarUnit) != 0) {
    // NSYearCalendarUnit is set
} else {
    // NSYearCalendarUnit is not set
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I need. By the way, is there any way to check if there's a calendar unit in unitFlags? Or to get all units in the variable?